# NV21 to I420 in android

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

**EDIT :** I came across this libyuv that does the NV21 to I420 conversion, but i don't really understand how to call it.

```
// Convert NV21 to I420.  Same as NV12 but u and v pointers swapped.
LIBYUV_API
int NV21ToI420(const uint8* src_y, int src_stride_y,
           const uint8* src_vu, int src_stride_vu,
           uint8* dst_y, int dst_stride_y,
           uint8* dst_u, int dst_stride_u,
           uint8* dst_v, int dst_stride_v,
           int width, int height)
```

I am passing the NV21 byte[] obtained from camera callback to the jni layer and converting it to unsigned char* as below

```
int yuvBufLen = env->GetArrayLength(yuvNV21);
unsigned char* yuvNV21Buf = new unsigned char[yuvBufLen];
env->GetByteArrayRegion(yuvNV21, 0, yuvBufLen,reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(yuvNV21Buf));
```

Now it is not clear to me how do i get the different parameters required to call the libyuv function NV21ToI420. What does each of the following parameters represent and 
 how to obtain them from the unsigned char* yuvNV21Buf I have ??

const uint8* src_y,
int src_stride_y,
const uint8* src_vu,
int src_stride_vu,
uint8* dst_y,
int dst_stride_y,
uint8* dst_u,
int dst_stride_u,
uint8* dst_v,
int dst_stride_v

I have checked this [obtain yuv420 in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873980/3437573) which explains how to get all the required parameters to call libyuv::NV12ToI420.

Can someone please explain me how to achieve this??

I am capturing frame byte[] from camera through the preview callback below

```
@Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frameData, Camera camera) {
```

The frameData am getting is in NV21 format and I am trying to convert NV21 to I420.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to I420?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: working on video conferencing app, and server needs I420 format. When I transmit NV21 from Android it looks distorted on server.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match

Comment: Exactly same..my image looks distorted like the one shown in the above link (2nd image)... it happens because my server treats it as I420, so I have to convert it to I420 to make it work..any ideas how to convert NV21 to I420??

Comment: If I've got my formats straight, NV21 is semi-planar, while I420 is planar.  So it's not a simple matter of swapping U and V.  You have to convert from "all U values, then all V values" to "alternating U and V values".

Comment: so isn't there any means by which i can achieve the desired I420??

Comment: You have the frame data.  Modify your code to shuffle the color bytes around.  It's more involved than a simple U/V swap, but you're just changing it from YYYYYYYYUUUUVVVV to YYYYYYYYVUVUVUVU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get to work the method I posted in the question, it kept crashing.

But thanks to Peter I found this [NV21ToI420](https://github.com/PeterXu/IvyVideo/blob/master/trunk/ivyvideo/src/IvyUtil.cpp) conversion and it worked perfect for me.

Simply it needs the NV21 and the I420 pointer.

```
unsigned char* yuvPtr; //NV21 data
unsigned char* I420 = new unsigned char[sourceWidth*sourceHeight*1.5]; //destination I420 pointer where the converted yuv will be stored 
NV21toI420(yuvPtr, I420, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
```

Thats all....

Answer (score 0):

adding to this (since the link in the answer seems to be expired). One can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983502/how-can-i-convert-android-bitmap-to-nv12-color-format) code to convert YUV format into NV21.

So I modified the code like this to convert it to I420. [Code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902368/3192693). Now it's working fine for mediaEncoder generated video.