# Convert camera images received from Tango from default YCRCB_420_SP to YUV_420_888

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm building Unity+Tango android app. In my `OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler` [handler](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/interface/i-tango-video-overlay) I receive images with format `17`, which corresponds to [`YCRCB_420_SP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21) (NV21) format. I however, need images in generic YUV_420_888 format. Thus, it's either need to be converted (how?) or requested originally from the camera during setup.

Is the latter possible? If not, any pointers on how to do the former?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715479/nv21-to-i420-in-android

Comment: I ended up converting it myself, in C++, since it's way faster. thanks!